# Insert multiple string inside one string using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, join, position, slice

I'm trying to insert multiple strings at multiple positions in another string but without any luck

This is the code I have tried.

```js
elInnerHtml = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

var testPos = ["10", "15", "20"];
var output = '';
cnt = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < testPos.length; i++) {
  output += [elInnerHtml.slice(0, testPos[i]), '<span class="Test-' + ++cnt + '">', elInnerHtml.slice(testPos[i])].join('');
}

console.log(output);
```

When I run the code it show many of the same line of code. How can I fix this?

Comment: Apologies Niroh, we edited at the same time, and I reverted some of your edits. It should be OK now. Please try to keep chatty material in posts to a minimum here - we prefer technical writing wherever possible.

Comment: Okay, when I saved the edit, I did see I made a mistake, the ++cnt code should be '<span class="TEST-' + ++cnt + '">' and not '<span class="TEST-" + ++cnt + "">'

Comment: where should `<span>` end? please add the wanted result.

Comment: It should be +1 character ahead, so lorem ipsum<span>l</span>orem ipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array by iterating from the right side, because the string changes the indices for added span elements.

```js
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    indices = [10, 15, 20],
    result = indices.reduceRight((s, p, i) => `${s.slice(0, p)}<span class="test-${i + 1}">${s.slice(p, ++p)}</span>${s.slice(p)}`, string);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for, I need it to be inside a for loop, so that i can make the class name of the span class="test-1" class="test-2" class="test-3" and so on :)

Comment: no poblem, you could take an counter as well by using the index of the array.

Comment: How do I check if the value in the array is -1 ? thanks

Comment: what should happen, if?

Comment: then it should not add the span

Comment: just filter it out in advance: `indices.filter(v => v !== -1)`